How can i format Json data for Powershell?
How can i format the following json body to make a rest request inb powershell az cli ?
It has json data in json data , its a bit different than the standard .
 {"Id":"1234","Name":"acme","Model":{"CustId":"789","CustName":"","Roles": 
   ["admin"]},"SubscriptionId":1,"Email":"cust@test.com"}

How do i format this in Powershell ?

Passing a JSON string as an az argument indeed requires quoting (enclosure in '...' in the simplest case), but the surprising part is that the embedded " characters must be escaped as "", for the reasons explained in the linked duplicate.

Your JSON data is not formatted strange in any way, but you need to handle the expression as a string in PowerShell first...
'{
  "Id":"1234",
  "Name":"acme",
  "Model":
  {
    "CustId":"789",
    "CustName":"",
    "Roles":["admin"]
  },
  "SubscriptionId":1,
  "Email":"cust@test.com"
}'

